# Data mining algorithm selection for 3 classes with negative and positive values

Tags: algorithm, matlab, selection

I am trying to handle a data set on matlab with 3 classes and negative and positive values on attributes. I tried naive bayes classifier but matlab says tha naive bayes can't handle negative values. Svm algorithm also can't handle this problem because there are 3 classes. So, i am asking you which algorithm to chose?

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simples solution that comes to mind is a k-NN classifier using majority voting. Say you want to classify a point and you use 10 nearest neighbours. Let's say that six out of 10 are class 1, two neighbours are class 2 and the two remaining neighbours are class 3, so in this case you would classify your point as class 1.

If you want to include nonlinearity (as in the case of SVM) you can use nonlinear kernels in k-NN too which basically means modifying the distance calculation.

Answer (score 0):

citing wikipedia:

Multiclass SVM[edit]Multiclass SVM aims to assign labels to instances by using support vector machines, where the labels are drawn from a finite set of several elements.

The dominant approach for doing so is to reduce the single multiclass problem into multiple binary classification problems.[8] Common methods for such reduction include:[8] [9]

Building binary classifiers which distinguish between (i) one of the labels and the rest (one-versus-all) or (ii) between every pair of classes (one-versus-one). Classification of new instances for the one-versus-all case is done by a winner-takes-all strategy, in which the classifier with the highest output function assigns the class (it is important that the output functions be calibrated to produce comparable scores). For the one-versus-one approach, classification is done by a max-wins voting strategy, in which every classifier assigns the instance to one of the two classes, then the vote for the assigned class is increased by one vote, and finally the class with the most votes determines the instance classification.
Directed Acyclic Graph SVM (DAGSVM)[10]
error-correcting output codes[11]
Crammer and Singer proposed a multiclass SVM method which casts the multiclass classification problem into a single optimization problem, rather than decomposing it into multiple binary classification problems.[12] See also Lee, Lin and Wahba.[13][14]